# Bindings, properties and object persistence

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, object-persistence

First: I really hope I placed the question at the right place so please correct me if I am on the wrong track..!

I have a window to display data that is updated in intervals in a table view. This data is managed by a `Controller` object which is the data source of the tableview. The `WindowController` has a controller property that is bound to the `Controller` object in IB:

```
@implementation WindowController

- (id) initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    if (self) {
        _controller = [[Controller alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) windowDidLoad {
...
```

Additionally, I have a `WindowHandler` class that has a static reference to the 'WindowController' with class methods to open and close the window:

```
static WindowController * windowController = nil;

@implementation WindowHandler

+ (void) initialize {
    if (self == [WindowHandler class]) {
        if (!windowController) {
            windowController = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:kWindowNibKey];
        }
    }
}

+ (void) showWindow:(id)sender {
    [windowController showWindow:sender];
}

...
```

Because I want to monitor the data that is to be displayed in the window even before the window is opened the first time, I do a `[WindowHandler initialize]` in my `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. This initiates the `WindowController` and therefore the `Controller` object. The Controller starts monitoring the data after launching which is my desired outcome.

The problem arises when the window is opened for he first time: a new instance of the `Controller` object is initiated, obviously when the window nib is loaded. From this time two `Controller` objects are running and observing the data which is not only unnecessary but also increases CPU usage. Further more, I suspect this to infrequently lead to crashs (sometimes I do get exceptions saying  'insertRowsAtIndexes:withRowAnimation: can not happen while updating visible rows!').

I guess I miss something in the concept of object properties or maybe in the concept of bindings. 
Is there something I do wrong? Or is there a good way of doing what I attempt to do?
Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would trigger initWithWindowNibName twice for your WindowController class?  "When the window is opened for the first time" -- you aren't doing this programattically?  It's mainmenu.xib or something?   You need to not init two windowControllers if you don't need two WCs.

Comment: @stevesliva: Thanks for your reply!  I don't no what is triggering initWithWindowNibName twice, this is what's puzzling me. The window can be opened from various points in my app (from a menu, by pressing a key shortcut or by pressing a button in another window). To open the window I do `[WindowController openWindow:nil]` (I edited the code so you can see the method).

Comment: Set breakpoints on `initWithWindowNibName` and `initialize` and watch the call stack on each invocation.   I think you should avoid explicitly calling `initialize`.  I can't explain why it would init your static variable twice, though.  I was thinking the runtime was nesting your explicit initialize in its automagic initialize, but I can't see how you'd get two... `dispatch_once` might help (see modern singleton code patterns), but understanding why it's done twice would be better.

Comment: @stevesliva: **SOLVED** `initialize` was called twice after beeing called from `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. Looking at the object id I could still tell that only one `Controller` object was initiated while a second would be initiated when the window was opened for the first time. Following your next hint in my `AppDelegate` I changed the statement from `[WindowHandler initialize]` to `[WindowController closeWindow:nil]`,`initialize` was only called once and the running `Controller` object was the same after opening the window. I still don't fully understand why.. But thank you very much!

Comment: @stevesliva: Sorry, I was wrong, but now I'm totally puzzled. Actually, neither `initialize` nor `initWithWindowNibName:` are called twice as determined by breakpoints (--> set to ignore once). But still two `Controller` objects are initiated, both after app finished launching. In the meantime I created a `DataMonitor` class to that other objects can register as observers. This way I can see that two objects are initialzed, but I can't even tell which one will be the one that is the data source of my tableview. I have no clue what's going on..